# Laravel: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1822 Failed to add the foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am new to laravel and to programming in general and am having problem migrating on my laravel project.
I am trying to create a database for FAQ with one to many relations between the tables 'questions' and 'question_category'.
I cant seem to migrate it without errors.
Here is the error below,

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1822 Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'questions_question_category_id_foreign' in the referenced table 'question_category' (SQL: alter table `questions` add constraint `questions_question_category_id_foreign` foreign key (`question_category_id`) references `question_category` (`id`) on delete cascade)
```

If someone can help it will be of great help. Thankyou.

**question_category table/migration**

```
        Schema::create('question_category', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id');
            $table->string('question_category_title');
            $table->mediumText('description')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**questions table/migration**

```
        Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('question');
            $table->mediumText('answer')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('question_category_id');
            $table->foreign('question_category_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('question_category')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

Comment: What did the error **say**? Use that information to fix/update the *referenced table* before adding the foreign key constraint.

Comment: Sorry I didnt understand much of this error. The error says that an index is missing from constraint. Could you tell me what that means? By referenced table do you mean the 'questions' table?

Comment: The error means you can't add a foreign key to a field that is not backed by an index. If the field is the primary key (e.g. an auto incrementing field or one you manually stated is primary using `->primary()`) then mysql creates the index by itself however if it's not the primary key you need to [create an index](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#indexes) on the field before it can be used as a foreign key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change datatype of the foreign key field in the questions table

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('question_category_id');
```

change primary key datatype in question category table

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
```

Comment: Thanks @Bhargav I tried this and this time it is giving me an error "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'question_category_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'questions_question_category_id_foreign' are incompatible."

Comment: When I change the data type in 'questions' table to $table->unsignedBigInteger('id') now it gives me the same error as the one in my question..

Comment: ok I edited my answer try that

Comment: Thank you so much @Bhargav the incompatible error was fixed using bigIncrements and unsignedBigInteger together.

Answer (score 0):

Replace it with **questions table/migration**

```
Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('question');
            $table->mediumText('answer')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('question_category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('question_category_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('question_category')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

Now dump both table as `question_category` and `questions` or use `php artisan migrate:fresh` (which will remigrate your tables) and check it.
Thank you.